# Access to User Outlook Calendar from REST API

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm struggling a bit with Microsoft authentication architecture to access resources using the Graph API.

Let me explain my use-case: I have an Outlook account, which I need to insert events into the Calendar. I also have a REST API, in Node.js, that should read these events, using `/me/events` or `/users/{id}/events` Graph endpoint.

Since it is only one user, I don't need to implement login, but rather have the REST API be able to get an Authorization token to access these resources.

I tried to use the `ConfidentialClientApplication` class to login using the `client_id` and `client_secret` for my application (configured through Azure), but whenever I call the Microsoft Graph after login, I receive a `401`.

Assuming that the problem is that the login I'm performing is with an admin account, I added the *Application* type `Calendars.Read` permission, to no help.

What am I doing wrong?
I just need to access this users' Calendar :(

Thanks for making it this far!

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ConfidentialClientApplication` to get an access token and call Microsoft Graph API to read users' Calendar, try the code below :

```
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const tenant= '<your tenant ID/name>'
const appID= '<azure ad app id>'
const appSec = '<azure ad app sec>'

const userID = '<user ID/UPN>'

const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: appID,
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant,
        clientSecret: appSec
    }
}

function readUserCalendar(userID,accessToken){
    const URL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/'+userID+'/events?$select=subject'
   fetch(URL,{headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  accessToken}})
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(json => console.log(json));
}

const pca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);
const acquireAccessToken = pca.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
    scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
  });

acquireAccessToken.then(result=>{readUserCalendar(userID,result.accessToken)})
```

Permissions grand to azure ad app in this case :
[image]

My test account calendar data:
[image]

Result :

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!

I've tried with your approach, which is very similar to what I had, but had no luck. Later found out two potential issues:

1. I was using the tenant config wrong,
2. I was not using a proper Azure subscription, but just trying with my personal account.

Even after trying with a free trial subscription, I couldn't really get it to work. Too bad, I really like the Microsoft Graph API but it's very complicated to get it working.